# Get filtered content from text file with Get-Content

Tags: powershell

I'm a bit stuck here. Basically I have a script that reads directory and filepath from a text file.

I want to filter them by *driveletter* and *exclude* paths like `program files` and the `C:\Windows` Directory. There is a variable for each driveletter But when I use the piece of code below it does not seem to filter anything. It does not seem to matter if the *Contains* has `C` `E` or `G` in it. it wil always put the **whole** content of the `SaveMe.txt` file in every variable.

Any advice?

```
$CDrive = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt | where { $_.length -gt 4 -and ($_.Contains("C:\")) -and $_ -NotContains "Program Files" -or "C:\Program Files (x86)" -or "C:\Windows" }
$EDrive = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt | where { $_.length -gt 4 -and ($_.Contains("E:\")) -and $_ -NotContains "Program Files" -or "C:\Program Files (x86)" -or "C:\Windows" }
$GDrive = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt | where { $_.length -gt 4 -and ($_.Contains("G:\")) -and $_ -notcontains "Program Files" -or "C:\Program Files (x86)" -or "C:\Windows" }
```

Comment: how's your `$PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt` looks like?

Comment: contains full paths like C:\Users\$env:username\Documents
C:\Users\$env:username\Pictures
C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop
C:\Users\$env:username\Favorites
C:\Users\$env:username\Music
C:\Users\$env:username\Videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

Solution 1:

```
$CDrive = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt | where { $_.length -gt 4 -and $_.Contains("C:\") -and !$_.Contains("Program Files") -and !$_.Contains("C:\Windows") }
$EDrive = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt | where { $_.length -gt 4 -and $_.Contains("E:\") -and !$_.Contains("Program Files") -and !$_.Contains("C:\Windows") }
$GDrive = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt | where { $_.length -gt 4 -and $_.Contains("G:\") -and !$_.Contains("Program Files") -and !$_.Contains("C:\Windows") }
```

Solution 2:

```
$CDrive = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt | where { $_.length -gt 4 -and ($_.Contains("C:\")) -and $_ -Notlike "*Program Files*" -and $_ -Notlike "*C:\Windows*" }
$EDrive = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt | where { $_.length -gt 4 -and ($_.Contains("E:\")) -and $_ -Notlike "*Program Files*" -and $_ -Notlike "*C:\Windows*" }
$GDrive = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt | where { $_.length -gt 4 -and ($_.Contains("G:\")) -and $_ -Notlike "*Program Files*" -and $_ -Notlike "*C:\Windows*" }
```

Comment: That is not how the [`-contains` operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use -like and -notlike. Contains is for checking if something is in the array, not a string

Comment: But it checks the content that was piped into $_, isn't that sort of an array? Please correct me if I'm wrong! :)

Comment: no, thats an object and you are "working" against a string representation of a property of that object

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification! Still learning the powershell ropes.

Comment: you are welcome, but choose something as an answer and upvote helpful answers, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you should use the builtin compare function `-like` and `-notlike`. Also you can't combine the `-or` statements without specifiying the compare function again.

However, I think [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) would make this more readable:

```
$CDrive = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt |  where { $_ -match 'C:\\(?!Windows\\|Program Files\\|Program Files \(x86\)\\).+'}
$EDrive = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt |  where { $_ -match 'E:\\(?!Windows\\|Program Files\\|Program Files \(x86\)\\).+'}
$GDrive = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt |  where { $_ -match 'G:\\(?!Windows\\|Program Files\\|Program Files \(x86\)\\).+'}
```

Answer (score 0):

optimized solution (file open only 1x)

```
$CDrive=@()
$EDrive=@()
$GDrive=@()

Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\SaveMe.txt | where { $_.length -gt 4 -and $_ -notlike "*Program Files*" -and $_ -notlike "*C:\Windows*" } | %{ if ($_.Contains("C:\")) {$CDrive+=$_};if ($_.Contains("E:\")) {$EDrive+=$_};if ($_.Contains("G:\")) {$GDrive+=$_};}
```

Comment: You are missing C:\Program Files (x86). Also a folder containg `Program Files` will be excluded as well.

Comment: no. If not contains 'Program Files', then not contain 'C:\Program Files (x86)'

Comment: So, a folder `C:\myApp\native Program Files\` will be excluded which is probably not what he wants

Comment: he write this :       -NotContains "Program Files"     and not -notin  "Program Files"

Comment: with his code, i think he want exclude "Program Files". So it's redundant. Now method is gived to him

Comment: Yes that should be the full path instead of just program files. Only a draft for testing.