# How do I use Get-Content to retrieve specific line and column from text file

Tags: powershell

*Example from the iperf3.txt file created.*

> [SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   312 Mbits/sec                  sender
> [SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   312 Mbits/sec                  receiver

I would like to be able to "extract" the **312 Mbits/sec**-text and leave the rest alone.
Previous I've used this line of code to "present" the numbers from the iPerf-speedtest after the PS-script was completed, but the entire line is displayed like the example, I put in above.

`Get-Content -Path $iperf3.txt | Where-Object {$_ -like'*[SUM]*0.00-15.00*'}`

I've been looking at this post [Get filtered content from text file with Get-Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606657/get-filtered-content-from-text-file-with-get-content) and wondered if that is what is needed to do what I want.

I would like to end result to be something like this:

> Your speedtest result is 123 Mbits/sec for download.
> Your speedtest result is 321 Mbits/sec for upload.

Any input or feedback would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDITED/UPDATED**
More text from the text-file.
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  5]   0.00-30.00  sec   116 MBytes  32.5 Mbits/sec   91             sender
[  5]   0.00-30.00  sec   116 MBytes  32.3 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[  7]   0.00-30.00  sec   116 MBytes  32.6 Mbits/sec   94             sender
[  7]   0.00-30.00  sec   116 MBytes  32.4 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[  9]   0.00-30.00  sec   109 MBytes  30.5 Mbits/sec  107             sender
[  9]   0.00-30.00  sec   108 MBytes  30.2 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 11]   0.00-30.00  sec   120 MBytes  33.5 Mbits/sec   98             sender
[ 11]   0.00-30.00  sec   119 MBytes  33.3 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 13]   0.00-30.00  sec   108 MBytes  30.2 Mbits/sec  101             sender
[ 13]   0.00-30.00  sec   107 MBytes  29.9 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 15]   0.00-30.00  sec   123 MBytes  34.3 Mbits/sec  104             sender
[ 15]   0.00-30.00  sec   122 MBytes  34.0 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 17]   0.00-30.00  sec   102 MBytes  28.5 Mbits/sec  104             sender
[ 17]   0.00-30.00  sec   101 MBytes  28.3 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 19]   0.00-30.00  sec   108 MBytes  30.2 Mbits/sec  108             sender
[ 19]   0.00-30.00  sec   107 MBytes  30.0 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 21]   0.00-30.00  sec   103 MBytes  28.8 Mbits/sec  105             sender
[ 21]   0.00-30.00  sec   102 MBytes  28.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 23]   0.00-30.00  sec   125 MBytes  34.9 Mbits/sec   96             sender
[ 23]   0.00-30.00  sec   124 MBytes  34.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.10 GBytes   316 Mbits/sec  1008             sender
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.10 GBytes   314 Mbits/sec                  receiver

For each speedtest iPerf will add the above content to the text-file, so in theory it will could be added two-three times. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Theo. Thanks for the update to the script. Sadly, it doesn't generate any output when used :(

switch -Regex -File 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\iperf3.txt' {
>>     '\[SUM].*\s(\d+ Mbits/sec)\s(?:[^\s]+\s)?(\w+)$' {
>>         # define the text. if 'sender' then 'upload', otherwise 'download'
>>         $updown = if ($matches[2] -eq 'sender') { 'upload' } else { 'download' }
>>         'Your speedtest result is {0} for {1}' -f $matches[1], $updown
>>     }
>> }
PS C:\Users\Me\Desktop>

Comment: Looks like you didn't copy/paste it correctly. At first glance, you missed the backslash to the left of the opening square bracket in the regex. Because of that, it will not match the line..(`[` has special meaning in regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing if there is more text in that file and how large it may be, here's two options for you:

```
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\iperf3.txt'| 
Where-Object { $_ -match '\[SUM].*\s(\d+ Mbits/sec) (\w+)$'} | 
ForEach-Object {
    # define the text. if 'sender' then 'upload', otherwise 'download'
    $updown = if ($matches[2] -eq 'sender') { 'upload' } else { 'download' }
    'Your speedtest result is {0} for {1}' -f $matches[1], $updown
}
```

If the file is huge, this would work faster and consumes less memory:

```
switch -Regex -File 'D:\Test\iperf3.txt' {
    '\[SUM].*\s(\d+ Mbits/sec) (\w+)$' {
        # define the text. if 'sender' then 'upload', otherwise 'download'
        $updown = if ($matches[2] -eq 'sender') { 'upload' } else { 'download' }
        'Your speedtest result is {0} for {1}' -f $matches[1], $updown
    }
}
```

Regex details:

```
\[                  Match the character “[” literally
SUM]                Match the characters “SUM]” literally
.                   Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s                  Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
(                   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d               Match a single digit 0..9
      +             Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \ Mbits/sec      Match the characters “ Mbits/sec” literally
)                  
\                   Match the character “ ” literally
(                   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   \w               Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      +             Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)                  
$                   Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

---

Now that you have shown more of the file, I noticed that the lines `sender` all have an extra numeric value in front of the word `sender`, which wasn't there in your earlier example.

Because of that, we need to adjust the regex.

This new code should ten work:

```
switch -Regex -File 'D:\Test\iperf3.txt' {
    '\[SUM].*\s(\d+ Mbits/sec)\s(?:[^\s]+\s)?(\w+)$' {
        # define the text. if 'sender' then 'upload', otherwise 'download'
        $updown = if ($matches[2] -eq 'sender') { 'upload' } else { 'download' }
        'Your speedtest result is {0} for {1}' -f $matches[1], $updown
    }
}
```

Regex details:

```
\[                      Match the character “[” literally
SUM]                    Match the characters “SUM]” literally
.                       Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s                      Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
(                       Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d                   Match a single digit 0..9
      +                 Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \ Mbits/sec          Match the characters “ Mbits/sec” literally
)
\s                      Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
(?:                     Match the regular expression below
   [^\s]                Match any character that is NOT a “A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)”
      +                 Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \s                   Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
)?                      Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(                       Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   \w                   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      +                 Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
$                       Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

Comment: Hello Theo. Sorry about the missing details. I'll edit the post tonight with more informations about the text-file.

Comment: So I've tried out both metods suggested, but none of them worked properly :(
I might be doing something wrong. I began researching about RegEx, and found a website that suggested the following line:
> \[SUM]   0\.00-30\.00  sec  1\.10 GBytes   [0-9]+ [a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+                  receiver

As I'm a noob to RegEx to say the least, I have no idea how to use this. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: @JesperSørensen Please see my edit. There is a big difference in the example you now show than the one before, so the regex needed to be adjusted for that. BTW, the regex you found online will not work because [1] it doesn't escape the opening square bracket [2] doesn't capture the wanted info [3] seems to be hardcoded for `receiver` only [4] doesn't account for the fact that the extra numeric value in the line is there only in some of the cases.